# sqlite3_open how to determine if file database created freshly?

Tags: c, sqlite

Newbie to sqlite3.

Correct me if my understand is wrong?.

sqlite3_open ( filename, &dbConnection) ->

```
1) This API creates an database [ie: filename], if it does not exists, and sets
the context to dbConnection. 
2) If the database exists already it just sets the context to dbConnection.
```

Both the case (1) & (2) returns SQLITE_OK.

Question: Now is there any possibility to filter if the database created first time?.

For Example:
     sqlite3_open (... )
     if ( first time created the database) { create table }

One possibility is to check the existence of the file, but i dont want to do that. Any alternative way from sqlite3 itself?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use create table if not exist syntax for that.

[image: Sqlite Create Table]